# Play framework errors in build.sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt

This is my build.sbt file :

```
name := """play-scala-starter-example"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
libraryDependencies += guice
dependencyOverrides+= "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.196"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn" % "2.2.0"
```

I'm getting the next errors :

```
cannot resolve symbol PlayScala and guice
and on all rows I'm getting "Expression type Def.Settings(Seq[ModuleID]] must conform to DslEntry in sbt.file
```

Moreover when the autocorrect doesn't recognize the type of all my objects (for example dataframes), it shows "Any". Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the plugin `PlayScala` in your project, you have to add:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.13")
```

to the file `<root_project_dir>/project/plugins.sbt` (you should create this file if does not exists)

Comment: It exists and that is exactly its content